# can not do call with dynamic credentials : bistri.conference.min.js

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call with Bistri API
For that, I am using following credentials

1. User Name
2. User ID
3. Remote User ID

**I am using bistri.conference.min.js and conference.js**

It is working fine if I use the credentials static.
But when I make it dynamic it connects fine but the call is not working showing the alert message:

> "The user you try to reach is currently offline"

Please help. Your help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Show code. How do you imagine we will help without knowing what have you done?

Comment: Hi, I have used same js for make the video call and tried with static credentials. With static data it is working fine but when i am setting the credentials from text file then it is not able to make video call.

I have used the demo code from here. https://github.com/bistri/api-samples/tree/master/javascript/one-2-one-video-call-example
they are using static value for credential and i have tried with set that from text file.

Please let me know if you want more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code? Do you use the user id for the call method?

If you use directly the conference.js, you must run the bc.init method after the user id and name initialization. If you don't do it, they will be undefined for bistri API.